# On the domain of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the domain of the function:$\sqrt{x-1}\sqrt{x+1}$

my answer was $$D_f=\left[1,\infty\right)$$
But there is another answer says that $-1$ is included in the domain because $f(-1)=0$

Comment: $-1$ is not in the domain since $\sqrt{-1-1}$ makes no sense (over the reals, of course).

Comment: I said so but the second answer depends on the definition of the real valued function that says a function is said to be real valued if is assigns a real valued to each number in its domain and that agree with -1

Comment: We have by definition $f(-1)=\sqrt{-1-1}\sqrt{-1+1}$ and it makes no sense. If you define $f$ as $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-1}$ then the domain is $(-\infty,-1]\cup [1,\infty).$ But this is a different function.